# PHP POST + iOS Swift error

Tags: php, ios, swift

I'm having trouble with my App, what I am trying to do is send some information from my textfields through a "NSMutableURLRequest" URL to a PHP file I have.

The error says there are undefined indexes for each of my vars.

This is the first time I do this kind of exercises so I don't know if the error is in my PHP code or in the Swift Function.

Below is my swift function.

```
  @IBAction func enviarInfo(_ sender: Any) {
          let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://www.mydomain/index.php")! as URL)
          request.httpMethod = "POST"


          //The String with the vars that will be sent to the $_POST["var"]
          let postString = "nombre = \(nombreText.text!) &aPaterno = \(apaternoText.text!) &aMaterno = \(amaternoText.text!) &genero = \(genero.text!) &email = \(emailText.text!) &telefono = \(telefonoText.text!)"


          request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

          let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
          data, response, error in

          if error != nil {
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
            }

          print("response = \(String(describing: response))")

          let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
          print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
          }
      task.resume()     
    }
```

The PHP code looks like this

```
  $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
  //All the $vars look like this.

     echo $nombre;
```

I would appreciate your help :)

Comment: Have you tried removing the spaces `nombre = \(...)` from your `postString`? You could also do a `var_dump($_POST)` to see what you're actually getting.

Comment: Thank You Magnus Ericsson! It worked!Haven't thought the String could be affected by the spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the spaces from your `postString`.

Change:

```
let postString = "nombre = \(nombreText.text!) &aPaterno = ..."
```

to

```
let postString = "nombre=\(nombreText.text!)&aPaterno=..." ...and so on
```

When sending data like that, those extra spaces matters when the string get's parsed.